Notepad++ Regex search with characters before and after IP address
I have a huge file with text before and after many IP addresses. I'm trying to extract just the IP addresses that fall within x.x.x.x. The unique characters in the line look something like this:
|SIP=10.111.2.234|
How can I find all the SIP=X.X.X.X and extract just the x.x.x.x?

What have you tried so far regarding this?

Try the following:
SIP=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}


This is also capturing SIP=

Yes, as has been asked: How can I find all the SIP=X.X.X.X

Last sentence from question:  "extract just the x.x.x.x"

This does the job:
(?<=\|SIP=)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}

Demo & Explanation
